# Git merge "Already up to date"

Tags: git, version-control, git-merge, branching-and-merging

[image]I have a master branch and then I have 3 other branches A, B, C. I am trying to merge A into Master via

```
 git merge A
```

I get `Already up to date`

I guess that means A is based off master. But then how do I get the code changes in A into Master?

Comment: This means that branch (or commit) A is *already included in* `master`. Merge does not mean "make equal"; merge means "combine changes". These must be changes since some common starting point.

Comment: When the tip commit of branch A is already included in master, that tip commit *is* the common starting point. So the changes in A are automatically "no changes". That's why you can't merge it: it's already merged.

Comment: If the commit at the tip of branch A is *ahead of* the current (`master`) commit, then Git will compare the tip of `master` to the tip of `master` to see what is changed on `master` (nothing), and compare the tip of `master` to the tip of branch A to see what is changed there (presumably something). *This* kind of merge can be done. Git will normally do it as a "fast-forward", which is not really a merge at all, but you can force Git to make a real merge. But in your case the tip of A is *behind* (and part of), not ahead of, the tip of master.

Comment: How to force it?

Comment: Added photo above. There are major differences between branches.

Comment: What does the round circles on master at the end mean?

Comment: I have no idea how to interpret that picture, with its various little doodads. But if A is ahead of master and you do `git checkout master; git merge A` you'll get either a fast-forward non-merge "merge" that changes the commit to which `master` points, and hence the commit that's checked out; or you'll get a real merge, possibly with merge conflicts that you have to solve. If you get "Already up to date" that means A is already merged into master, and is equal (clearly not in this case) or behind.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The message “Already up-to-date” means that all the changes from the branch you’re trying to merge have already been merged to the branch you’re currently on. More specifically it means that the branch you’re trying to merge is a parent of your current branch.

Using a graphical tools of git look at your repository. The label for the “A” branch should be somewhere below your “master” branch label.

Your branch is up-to-date with respect to its parent. According to merge there are no new changes in the parent since the last merge. That does not mean the branches are the same, because you can have plenty of changes in your working branch and it sounds like you do.

One solution to remediate the problem is:

```
git checkout master
git reset --hard A
```

This brings it back to the 'A' level.

Then do:

```
git push --force origin master
```

in order to force changes back to the central repo.

Comment: Not sure how that is possible? Master is the base code. The developer made changes to Master and created a new branch A ( I can see about 50 lines of code added). I cloned Master and then tried to merge A into master (to get his new 50 lines of code) and that is when I get the Already Up To Date.

Comment: Have you check with a graphic tools for git what i said above?

Comment: See update of graphic. There are major difference between branch master and A (step-1-decypt)

Comment: In your image seems that the master branch is derived from branch decrypt, are you sure you derived decrypt branch from master?

Comment: fatal: ambiguous argument 'A': unknown revision or path not in the working tree.